Apache Drill cannot read windows local files
I'm new to Apache Drill. I want to try to use Drill to manage local data and configure the data storage path in the JSON file, but when I use SQL syntax to query the data, I can't read the local file.
I have installed Apache Drill and configured the file path in the JSON file (file name is 'data_access') as follows:
{
  "type": "file",
  "connection": "file:///",
  "workspaces": {
    "channel_0": {
      "location": "C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/DataFiles/Channel_0",
      "writable": false,
      "defaultInputFormat": null,
      "allowAccessOutsideWorkspace": false
    }
  },
  "formats": {
    "json": {
      "type": "json",
      "extensions": [
        "json"
      ]
    },
    "csv": {
      "type": "text",
      "extensions": [
        "csv"
      ],
      "lineDelimiter": "\n",
      "fieldDelimiter": ",",
      "quote": "\"",
      "escape": "\"",
      "comment": "#"
    },
    "parquet": {
      "type": "parquet"
    }
  },
  "authMode": "SHARED_USER",
  "enabled": true
}

When I use an SQL statement to query the data, the statement is as follows:
select * from data_access.channel_0.`20240806_205605.txt`;

The error is：

Error: VALIDATION ERROR: From line 1, column 15 to line 1, column 57: Object '20240806_205605.txt' not found within 'data_access.channel_0'

I can guarantee that the file (20240806_205605.txt) exists and has permission to read the file, but I don't know why I just can't read the file.


Use SHOW FILES IN data_access.channel_0 to get a view of what Drill sees there.
Make sure that one of your format configurations, probably the "csv" one, includes the file name extension "txt" so that it will match 20240806_205605.txt.

"extensions": [
    "txt"
]

